# Let $K$ be a field. Which of the following is a field: $(a) K[x] (b) K(x) (c) K[x]/I$ where $ I$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field. Which of the following is a field:
>
> $(a) K[x] $
>
> $(b) K(x)$
>
> $(c) K[x]/I$  where $ I$ is maximal

I understand $(a)$ isn't and $ (c)$ is a field. But I can't tell the difference between $(a)$ and $(b)$. What I've found is that $(b)$ is "the field of rational functions of  $x$".

Can you provide some examples of $(a)$ and $(b)$?

What I know is that $ K[x] = \{a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n : a_i \in K\}$

and I've used $K(x)$ when doing field extension problems.

Comment: A 'rational function' is a fraction of two polynomials. $K(x)$ denotes field extension while $K[x]$ denotes ring extension with element $x$.

Comment: You have $K[x]$ correctly. As a set, $K(x)= \{\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} : g(x),h(x)\in K[x], \quad h(x)\neq 0 \}$. Does this help? This can be viewed as the fraction field of the integral domain $K[x]$, or alternatively it can be viewed as the field extension of $K$ of the arbitrary variable $x$. Either way, certainly $K(x)$ is clearly a field almost tautologically.